# How to show data of a column using a Parameter in ssrs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

the result of a stored procedure returns a number of cities

I wrote this stored procedure to get the data of any column to show them in ssrs  report

here is the stored procedure

```
Alter PROCEDURE get_acc_Account_report @Variable NVARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max);
SET @SQL = 'Select '+ @Variable + ' From Acc_Account'
PRINT @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

Then I created a new report in the report builder that contains the dataset of this stored procedure,

How can I show the return data of the selected column of the returned Variable I write in the columns.

E.G.:-
I wrote this Expression

```
=Parameters!Variable.Value
```

but It was right to return me 'City' Column and it is true,
any recommendation for a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a static alias for your column in your procedure query.

```
SET @SQL = 'Select '+ @Variable + ' AS mycolumn From Acc_Account'
```

Then use the column alias as the field name of your dataset e.g. 
`=Fields!mycolumn.Value`

Comment: on refreshing the stored procedure again in the reporting server no dataset columns appears !